# ¿Cómo hacer para que cuando el usuario introduzca el cero (0) salga del ciclo en la primera vez y no en la segunda vez?

Tags: javascript, bucles, while

Saludos a toda la comunidad espero se encuentren muy bien.
Me llegó un pequeño simulador donde el usuario debe introducir o seleccionar alguna de las opciones del 1 al 5 y cuando introduzca el 0 (cero) salga del ciclo, lo que ocurre es que si lo hace pero no a la primera vez sino a la segunda vez que se introduce el cero... Quiero hacer que lo haga de inmediato y no esperar otro ciclo para poder salir. No encuentro la forma de hacerlo aunque he probado varias... ¿Alguna sugerencia? Gracias de antemano gente...

```
let itemUno ="Souvenir Woodland";
let itemDos ="Sirenita";
let itemTres ="Hermione Granger";
let itemCuatro = "Stitch";
let itemCinco ="Personaje estilo chibi";

let precioUno ="300";
let precioDos ="2.500";
let precioTres ="3.000";
let precioCuatro ="2.500";
let precioCinco ="Desde 2.500";

let entrada = parseInt(prompt("Ingrese una opción \n 1-Souvenir Woodland \n 2-Sirenita \n 3-Hermione Granger \n 4-Stitch \n 5-Personaje estilo chibi \n 0-SALIR"));

while(entrada > 0){
    if(entrada <= 5){
        console.log("El item elegido es: \n"+ obteneritem(entrada));
        alert("El item elegido es: \n"+ obteneritem(entrada));
    }else{
        console.log("El item elegido no existe. \n Por favor ingrese otra opción");
        alert("El item elegido no existe. \n Por favor ingrese otra opción");
    }
     entrada = parseInt(prompt("Ingrese una opción \n 1-Souvenir Woodland \n 2-Sirenita \n 3-Hermione Granger \n 4-Stitch \n 5-Personaje estilo chibi \n 0-SALIR"));
}

entrada = parseInt(prompt("Ingrese una opción \n 1-Souvenir Woodland \n 2-Sirenita \n 3-Hermione Granger \n 4-Stitch \n 5-Personaje estilo chibi \n 0-SALIR"));

function obteneritem(numeroItem){
    switch (numeroItem) {
        case 1:
            return "Item: " + itemUno + "\n Precio: $" + precioUno;
            
        case 2:
            return "Item: " + itemDos + "\n Precio: $" + precioDos;
            
        case 3:
            return "Item: " + itemTres + "\n Precio: $" + precioTres;
            
        case 4:
            return "Item: " + itemCuatro + "\n Precio: $" + precioCuatro;
            
        case 5:
            return "Item: " + itemCinco + "\n Precio: $" + precioCinco;
                
        default:
            return "El item seleccionado no existe";
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Pues tienes repetida la linea en que haces el prompt. Cuando ingresas 0 si se acaba el loop y continua la ejecucion, y la linea que le sigue (justo encima de tu `funcion obtenerItem`) vuelve a imprimir el prompt.

Comment: Muchas gracias Camilo, me di cuenta cuando ya había posteado la pregunta pero de todas formas excelente tu apoyo y respuesta

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usa un bucle `do ... while`, que siempre se ejecuta al menos una vez, luego si la entrada no es 0 la procesas y si es cero pues se sale del bucle.

```js
let itemUno ="Souvenir Woodland";
let itemDos ="Sirenita";
let itemTres ="Hermione Granger";
let itemCuatro = "Stitch";
let itemCinco ="Personaje estilo chibi";

let precioUno ="300";
let precioDos ="2.500";
let precioTres ="3.000";
let precioCuatro ="2.500";
let precioCinco ="Desde 2.500";
var entrada='';

do {
     entrada = parseInt(prompt("Ingrese una opción \n 1-Souvenir Woodland \n 2-Sirenita \n 3-Hermione Granger \n 4-Stitch \n 5-Personaje estilo chibi \n 0-SALIR"));
    if(entrada !=0) {
      if(entrada <= 5){
          console.log("El item elegido es: \n"+ obteneritem(entrada));
          alert("El item elegido es: \n"+ obteneritem(entrada));
      }else{
          console.log("El item elegido no existe. \n Por favor ingrese otra opción");
          alert("El item elegido no existe. \n Por favor ingrese otra opción");
      }
     } 
}
while (entrada !=0)

function obteneritem(numeroItem){
    switch (numeroItem) {
        case 1:
            return "Item: " + itemUno + "\n Precio: $" + precioUno;
            
        case 2:
            return "Item: " + itemDos + "\n Precio: $" + precioDos;
            
        case 3:
            return "Item: " + itemTres + "\n Precio: $" + precioTres;
            
        case 4:
            return "Item: " + itemCuatro + "\n Precio: $" + precioCuatro;
            
        case 5:
            return "Item: " + itemCinco + "\n Precio: $" + precioCinco;
                
        default:
            return "El item seleccionado no existe";
            break;
    }
}
```